# Python: function arguments and return values

Tags: python, function

Say I have a function

```
def equals_to(x,y):
 a + b = c
def some_function(something):
 for i in something:
 ...
```

Is there a way to use `c` that was calculated by `equals_to` as a parameter for `some_function` like this

```
equals_to(1,2)
some_function(c)
```

Comment: what are `c`, `a` and `b`? Where are they from?

Comment: I'm very confused by what you're trying to accomplish. `equals_to` doesn't compile, it looks like it's meant to return an integer, which wouldn't work in a `for x in blah` statement.

Comment: ` def equals_to(x,y)` should have said `def equals_to(a,b)` I made a mistake while typing out the example. Also `a + b = c` should have been `c = a + b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` the value of `c` from the function.

```
def equals_to(x,y):
    c = x + y           # c = x + y not a + b = c
    return c            # return the value of c 

def some_function(something):
    for i in something:
    ... 
    return 

sum = equals_to(1,2)     # set sum to the return value from the function 
some_function(sum)       # pass sum to some_function
```

Also the function signature of `equals_to` takes the arguments `x,y` but in the function you use `a,b` and your assignment was the wrong way round, `c` takes the value of `x + y` not `a + b` equals `c`.

Strongly recommend: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/